# Create a map with coordinates-based marker using Javascript, jQuery and/or php

Tags: javascript, canvas, geolocation, maps

I am developing a client-server application and I need to create or obtain a geographical map with some markers (just red points, for example) on it based on lat and lang.

I have been looking on the web but I couldn't find anything ok for me.

I could do it using google maps but I think I can't use my own custom map-image and my custom markers.

However, this is an example of what I'd like to do more or less having some coordinates:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [MapBox](http://mapbox.com/). You can create your own map and markers and then use it together with [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) or [Mapbox.js](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) to create a nice client-side map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.morrisda.com/?post=pointmap

Here explanation of how i managed this. With example !

Here source code:

```
function make_pointers(latitude, longitude) {

targetmap = document.getElementById("point_map");

 //it's sure it will work when your map is a perfec square, so it's got height on the x      and on the y for usefull debugging. 
 var asseX = $('#point_map').height()
 var asseY = $('#point_map').height()

 //lat and lang from imput
 lang = longitude;
 lat = latitude;

 var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326'); //source coordinates will be in     Longitude/Latitude, WGS84
 var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3785'); //destination coordinates in meters, global     spherical mercators projection, see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3785/

 var mercator_object = new Proj4js.Point(lang,lat); //any object will do as long as it has 'x' and 'y' properties

 Proj4js.transform(source, dest, mercator_object); 

 give_top = 19971868.8804*2 //this is how a meridian is long. 

 mercator_longitude = mercator_object.y //this is longitude by mercator

 //this switch is if latitude is negative; 
 if (mercator_object.y > 0) {mercator_object.y = mercator_object.y + give_top/2}
 if (mercator_object.y < 0 ) {mercator_object.y = give_top/2 + mercator_object.y}

 //this is my lovely proportion, value of give_top is length of a meridian
 mercator_distance = (asseY*mercator_longitude)/give_top;

 //distance from 0:
 y = asseY/2 - mercator_distance;

 //proportion to make working on x;

 //(180 + lang) makes lang from 0 to 360 instead of -180, +180.
 //to understand, now image equator as a line, long 360. 
 //now we divide our coords (from 0 to 360) for 360, and the result is how far is this point from 0 on a 360-long line. 
 //now a simple proportion, and we get this distance on a line long like x axis, which is the width of our map.

 // % is a Modulus (division remainder)

 normalized_x_coords = (180 + lang)

 x = (asseX * normalized_x_coords/ 360) % asseX;

 //let's put this little points on my map (subtract -3 cause our point is large 6.)

 console.log(x); //this is distance from left border; 
 console.log(y) //this is distance from bottom border
}
```

Remember you need jQuery and ProJ4js to use this. More info in previous link

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Slippy Map On Canvas](https://github.com/dfacts/Slippy-Map-On-Canvas) project that is a implemenation of a slippy tiles map using HTML5. You can configure your own map and markers, and it also supports many other features which may be useful for you.

Comment: Can you summarise the relevant details in the link in case the content changes or goes away?